# RabbitMQ User Authentication with dynamic users

Tags: security, ssl, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ with SSL/TLS in order to allow confidentiality, integrity and authentication. The message sent is encrypted using sender and broker certificates between sender and broker and then encrypted using broker and receiver certificates between broker and receiver.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
  {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.2']}]},
  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "...ca_certificate.pem"},
                    {certfile,   "...certificate_signed.pem"},
                    {keyfile,    "...private_key.pem"},
                    {password,  "pass"},
                    {verify,     verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true},
                    {versions, ['tlsv1.2']}]}
   ]}
```

However this is not enough because I need that a receiver/consumer to be able to assure the sender/publisher identification, like described in [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781849516501/2/ch02lvl1sec28/understanding-the-validated-user-id-extension). At the receiver I only can access certificate information from the broker certificate.

A solution to that would be to use **user-id** message property, like i found in the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/validated-user-id.html).
This property, sent in every message, will make sure that a message will only be published successfully if the user-id property is equal to the username used for that user to login in the RabbitMQ broker. Since I am already using certificates for SSL I will probably use them also to serve as user authentication with the broker as described [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyabecker/Using-SSL-client-certificates-for-authentication-with-RabbitMQ)

**My problem:**

I am using RabbitMQ for communication between agents in a simulation platform and agents are created dynamically, so I would need for dynamic user creation at RabbitMQ which seems not to be possible.

Does someone know if I can do dynamic user creation somehow? Or suggest another approach to my authentication problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The user-id property is not a security feature. It just sets information in the message header so that you can know who produced the message.

If you want authentication and autorization using certificates, you can follow the directives in the article you linked (https://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyabecker/Using-SSL-client-certificates-for-authentication-with-RabbitMQ), especially in the section "Configuring Client authentication via certificates".

In short, you need to install the rabbitmq-auth-mecanism-ssl plugin (see here https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl/blob/master/README.md) and configure it following the documentation. You also need to create a passwordless internal user in RabbitMQ that has the same CN (common name) as your certificate to be able to give it authorizations.

If you want everything to be automated (as it should be), each time you want to create a new agent, you have to :

- Generate a client key/certificate pair using openssl (see : https://superuser.com/questions/226192/avoid-password-prompt-for-keys-and-prompts-for-dn-information). Your key needs to be trusted by the same certificate authority that RabbitMQ trusts (in your SSL setup).
- Create a user in RabbitMQ using rabbitmqctl (https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

In my view, this is a very secure setup if you protect the generated keys so that only the agents have access to them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That is what I had think to do and I  should have mentioned it. However, I was looking for a solution that would not require so much startup/config time, specially because the user creation at RabbitMQ with rabbitmqctl is kinda slow. My posting idea was to look for another solution, considering that could not be one. Another thing that I am bit concerned is if I can reach some limit that RabbitMQ has related to number of registered users